# Batch script to search for a partial folder name by referencing a partial PC name

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'd like to create a batch file that can search for a partial folder name by referencing a partial PC name, using the common last 4 characters of each.

For instance, all PC's are named "computer####" and we have shared network folders named Store_####.

I need to be able to drop this bat file on remote PC's, which all have different last 4 digits in the PC and store names.  However, the last 4 of the computer names (at any given store) will always match the last 4 of the shared network folder.

The bat file needs to look at the computername, then search for the matching store number using the same last 4 digits, in a shared network drive... and then map it.

The first 3 lines work for mapping, but not for the map and search (for the S drive). I've been searching this site for 2 hours now. I'm a beginner at scripting. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
net use /PERSISTENT: YES

net use H: \\example.tn\users\%username% /p:YES

net use G: \\example.tn\shared /p:YES


net use S: \\example.tn\Stores\Store_%computername% /p:YES

if exist *name* (echo found it) else (echo not found)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you need the last 4 digits/chars from computername to identify the proper store? Use [substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) `%COMPUTERNAME:~-4%`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

set string=%computername:~5,4%

net use /PERSISTENT: YES

net use g: \example.tn\shared /p:YES

net use h: \example.tn\users\%username% /p:YES

net use S: "\example.tn\Stores\STORE_%string%" /p:YES

The ~5 ignores the first 5 characters, then the ,4 looks at the following 4 characters.

...TY for the input!